Tensorflow Reduce Tensor to Specified Degree using tf.math.reduce()
I am trying to reduce a conv output of x channels to y channels through a sum reduction. For example, if I have a output of (batches, h, w, d, 15), I want to reduce it to (batches, h, w, d, 5). I could not find a way to do this with the tf.math.reduce() function.
I tried using tf.math.reduce(), but it does not have a way to specify how many dimensions to keep. I also tried to reshape the tensor, but was not able to figure it out.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi @OPRESTON ,Use this line of code to combine 3 channel into 1 reshape = tf.reshape(input_tensor, (-1, input_tensor.shape[1], input_tensor.shape[2], input_tensor.shape[3], 5, 3))  and 'result_tensore = tf.reduce_sum(reshape, axis=-1)' to sum the dimension to reduce it.Insted of using tf.math.reduce() try tf.reduce_sum
